# UIWebview cuts 5 lines of text at the button with <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, uiwebview

I want to show some details of a Project in a UIWebView.

So here is the code of the site:

```
<html>
```

```
                    <style type="text/css">
                        body { font-family:Arial; }
                    </style>
```

```
                <body>
            <h1>Project Details</h1>
            <h2>Project: Blub</h2>
            <table>
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td>Manager:</td>
                    <td>Hansi</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Start:</td>
                    <td>2010-10-01 08:00:00.0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Finish:</td>
                    <td>2012-06-30 17:00:00.0</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
            <hr>
             <table border="0">
                 <tbody><tr valign="top">
                     <td>Report Date:</td>
                     <td colspan="3">2011-04-14 00:00:00.0</td>
                 </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                    <td>Current Status:</td>
                    <td><img alt="yellow" src="/Source/Yellow.gif"></td>
                    <td>Previous Status:</td>
                    <td><img alt="yellow" src="/Source/AltSlightYellow.gif"></td>
                </tr>
                 <tr valign="top">
                     <td>Measures</td>
                     <td colspan="3">- Here are some details blabalaasldfjlasdkfjlkasjfdlksdfldjslkdfjlksdfjlkjsdlkfj
</td>
                 </tr>
            </tbody></table>
```

So there is always about 3 lines of code which are cut.
But if you scoll up you can see that everything is available but it bounces back if you release the screen

So why the hell is it like this.

It doesnt matter how much description is written, there are always 3 lines left out

Im going nuts please help

https://picasaweb.google.com/hamisam/IphonePics?authkey=Gv1sRgCMX517DOq4f9tgE&feat=directlink

How i create my webview:

```
NSMutableString *address = [NSMutableString stringWithString: self.url];
 [address appendString:self.projectID];
 [address appendString:@".html"];

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:address];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];

[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Does the content disappear behind the Status bar ? or how exactly is it cut. Would you care to show us how you create your UIWebView ?

Comment: So i have uploaded some pics to show what i mean.
You can now see how im building up my Webview.
Look at the Pictures there you can see what i mean after:"2.1) Übergreifende Darstellungen" is cut and in the second picture you have to hold the finger to read the data, if you release the finger it bounces back to initial state....
Did you get my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your screenshot i can see what the problem is:

Your UIWebView seems to have fallen behind the status bar.

If you are using the interface editor, open up the xib and resize the uiwebview.
I believe you can check in the inspector to show a status bar in the top, and thhen resize the uiwebview accordingly.

If you are adding it programatticly, edit the cgrectmake to compensate your navigation bar.

Comment: Thank you very much, i didnt recognized ne toolbar in the buttom.
so i removed it with self.navigationController.toolbar.hidden = YES;
And I recognized that the height of the webview in the InterfaceBuilder was too much.
Thank you very much for your help I lost so much time searching for this Problem.